# keeping a line connection between two animating circles in animate CC (flash)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, canvas, adobe, animate-cc

I have two circles, with a line connecting their center points. I want to animate the position of the circles randomly, but keep the line attached to their centers no matter where they move. How do I do this (in code / as3?).

[image]

Comment: If you have a way of detecting when those circles move (eg: by user drag? auto-moved by code?) then you could use `LineTo()` inside an `enterFrame()` function. Also make sure each circle is inside (addChild'ed) it's own container (type Sprite or MClip) created by code. This way, the _starting_ x/y of line is circle_A container's width/height each divided by two. The _ending_ x/y is circle_B container's width/height each also divided by two.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Can the line be a part of the graphics object as VC.One suggests, or does it need to be a MovieClip or Bitmap? (the implementation is quite different depending on the answer to that question)

Comment: Thanks VC - if you submit this as an answer I'll accept it (I'm auto-moving by code)